# How to nest file_upload in button click in streamlit?

Tags: python, streamlit

I want to have a file upload widget pop up after clicking a button.
Currently when i am trying to upload a file it dissapears right after i upload it...
File_uploader works fine when it is outside the opt_select loop.

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import shutil


opt_select = st.selectbox(
    "Please select from one of the options",
    ("Abs", "Bgf")
)

if opt_select == "Abs":
    if st.button("Submit"):
        st.write("New created.")
        uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Upload text file", type=["txt"])
        if uploaded_file is not None:
            st.write("Success.")

        else:
            st.warning("No Selection")
```

Comment: by any chance, when you finish uploading - the page refreshes? is the file uploaded even though it disappears?

Comment: No,the file is not uploaded.